# How to do password validation in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, validation, encryption, passwords

I have encrypted my password field using aes_256 algorithm in sql server. The password field is now encrypted. Now I want to login user and the validation process should be done on the server.
The code which i wrote for the validation process is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Procedure_UserLogin
    @username varchar(50),
    @pwd varchar(50),
    @responseMessage INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @userID INT

    IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 username FROM userInfo WHERE username=@username)
    BEGIN
        open symmetric key key1
        decryption by certificate namecert
        SET @userID=(SELECT username FROM userInfo WHERE username=@username AND encryptedpwd=(ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('key1'),@pwd)))
        IF (@userID IS NULL)
            SET @responseMessage=0 /*INAVLID PASSWORD*/
        ELSE
            SET @responseMessage=1  /*VALID USERNAME AND PASSWORD*/
    END
    ELSE
        SET @responseMessage=2 /*INVALID USERNAME*/
END
```

But the response is always 0. Please tell me what mistake am i doing?

Comment: Don't encrypt passwords.  Anything that is encrypted can be decrypted. Salt and hash your passwords, and store the hash in the database.  When a user logs in, salt and hash the password and compare the resulting hash with the hashed value in the database.

Comment: You are selecting username (varchar) to @userID (Int).  I am surprised you do not get a conversion error.

Comment: @dbugger, I am not bringing my encrypted password to client side, and also i think aes_256 algorithm generates the result similar as done by the hash and salt together. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @JoeC, well even i am surprised that i didn't get a conversion error. Anyway, I have done the correction. Thanks

Comment: No, much different. And it exposes your users' passwords if your system is compromised. http://www.darkreading.com/safely-storing-user-passwords-hashing-vs-encrypting/a/d-id/1269374

Answer (score 1):

One can/should not delegate password verification to the database. Passwords should be **hashed** with a slow algorithm like BCrypt, PBKDF2 or SCrypt and those algorithms are usually not supported by database systems. Salting is mandatory and will prevent that you can search for a specific password-hash.

So do not encrypt the passwords, instead implement it like this:

```
// Get password-hash by user id
SELECT hashedpwd FROM userInfo WHERE username=@username

// Verify the password within your application, which supports a safe algorithm
// like BCrypt, PBKDF2 or SCrypt.
// Take the salt from $existingHashFromDb or from a separate db-field.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is because `ENCRYPTBYKEY` outputs different result every time, and an encrypted value stored in a table is constant.

Try running the script below to see it in action.

```
DECLARE @passphrase VARCHAR(50);
SET @passphrase = 'UseYourHashLuke';

OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY KEY1
DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE namecert

SELECT ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('KEY1'), @passphrase);

CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY1
GO 10
```

You should see 10 different outputs.  But if you run  SELECT statement against the table for `encryptedpwd`, the output is the same every time.  That's why your script can never correctly authenticate the user input even when the input is correct.

Now, based on that you might be thinking of changing this line

```
encryptedpwd=(ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('key1'),@pwd)))
```

to something like this, right?

```
DECRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('key1'),encryptedpwd)) = @pwd
```

Not so fast. The reason is that both `DECRYPTBYKEY`and `ENCRYPTBYKEY` returns `VARBINARY(8000)` but the user input `@pwd` is `VARCHAR(50)`.  So without converting  the output to match the datatype of input, they will always be different.

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR,DECRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('key1'),encryptedpwd))) = @pwd
```

Lastly, BOL on [`CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177938.aspx) says

> Open symmetric keys are bound to the session not to the security context. An open key will continue to be available until it is either explicitly closed or the session is terminated.

So it'd be a good practice to explicitly close keys at the end with.

```
CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY KEY1
```